# Whats the correct way to have Dockerfile build a react client app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm using Docker for a react/express app. The backend express app always builds the latest code, but the client react app does not. I have to manually run `cd client && npm run build` locally before `docker-compose up --build`. This is even the case if I completely destroy my containers/volumes using `docker system prune -a --volumes`.

Any tips on getting Docker to correctly build the client app like it does for the backend?

Dockerfile:

```
# Base image
FROM node:18.0.0 as builder

# Set environment variable for legacy OpenSSL
ENV NODE_OPTIONS --openssl-legacy-provider

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json
COPY package*.json ./

# Copy scripts and make them executable
COPY scripts/* ./scripts/
RUN chmod +x ./scripts/wait-for-it.sh
RUN chmod +x ./scripts/seed_once.sh
RUN chmod +x ./scripts/chmod.sh

# Install dependencies
RUN npm ci

# Copy the rest of the app's source code
COPY . .

# Change working directory to client
WORKDIR /app/client

# Run the build
RUN npm run build

# Production stage
FROM node:18.0.0

# Set environment variable for legacy OpenSSL
ENV NODE_OPTIONS --openssl-legacy-provider

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy built React app from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /app/client/build ./client/build

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json
COPY package*.json ./

# Install production dependencies
RUN npm ci --only=production

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python2 make postgresql-client


# Copy the rest of the source code to the container EXCLUDING scripts folder
COPY . .

# Copy scripts from builder stage
COPY --from=builder /app/scripts/ ./scripts/
USER root
RUN chmod +x ./scripts/wait-for-it.sh
RUN chmod +x ./scripts/seed_once.sh
RUN chmod +x ./scripts/chmod.sh
RUN ls -la scripts/
# Expose the port
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

```
version: '2.4'
services:
  greeny-db:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./src/configs/db_init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db_init.sql
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
  
  greeny-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      greeny-db:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgres@greeny-db:5432/greeny_db
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
      - ./public:/app/public
    command: ["npm", "start"]
  
  seeders:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      greeny-db:
        condition: service_healthy
    command: ["sh", "./scripts/seed_once.sh"]

volumes:
  greeny-db-data:
```

Comment: That Dockerfile seems like it should work.  How are you running the container; are you overwriting any part of the image's filesystem with `volumes:`?

Comment: Im using a volume for my database. I just edited and posted docker-compose. Its weird tho, I see the react app building in the output when i run docker-compose up --build, but the changes dont reflect.. its like some strange caching issue @DavidMaze

Comment: You have `volumes:` overwriting the image's `/app/src` (which I'd delete) but not `/app/client/build`, so that's not specifically the problem.  Do you have a `./client/build` directory on the host; is the `COPY . .` line in the final build stage overwriting the build application?